# Information regarding ways to freely travel within Europe during renewal of Permit in Italy

Tags: resident-permit, italy, residence-cards, austria

My fiancee lives in Austria and I live in Italy. Recently, she went on a trip outside Europe and would be returning soon. I found out today that my permit of stay/residence permit will be expiring one day after her return to Austria. And since the Italian system is completely broken, my fingerprint date is three months after the expiry date. Therefore six months would have passed before I can meet her. Due to other extraneous circumstances it would be infeasible for her to visit Italy.

Therefore, my question is what are my options to travel to Austria?

- I have the national identity card and have used it to travel within Europe. Although it does mention that my citizenship is not EU/Swiss.
- I can apply for a temporary Permit of Stay, but colleagues at the International office in my workplace told me that I need to show a need to travel (work related, extraneous family circumstances). I came across this [question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/10739/travel-within-eu-with-expired-german-aufenthaltstitel-residency-permit) related to a similar situation in Germany. I think it's the german version of the temporary permit of stay.
- I can apply for a Schengen Visa in the Austrian Embassy in Bratislava, Ljubljana or Munich.

What are my other options? Can I somehow show need to travel?